# Why we say "More than one person "is""?

Tags: grammar

I'm always curious about why we have to use "is" or "does" when we mention "more than one thing" though this phrase means few people, not one person. Please let me know if you don't mind, and sorry for gramatically incorrect sentences cuz I'm not a native.

Comment: Thx for informing me of the page! However, still I can't understand the logic of this grammer though I've understood that this expression is conventional one. What do natives image when they hear "more the one ~"?